# A Little Cryptic Puzzle

Tags: cryptic-clues

Nothing too complicated here, solve the six cryptics and find the final answer to this puzzle :)

Cult or area (6)
Reshot fails strangers (6)
Announces hole prices (6)
Programming string about single smoker (6)
Fungi, so treat salads first (6)
Road before holy three-dimensional prefix (6)

(Bonus question: which clue is the odd one out?)

Comment: The length=6 says they are left over clues of the last puzzle ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Answers:

> `SECT + OR`; `OTHERS*`; `O+RATES`; `ST(ONE)R`; `ERGO + T_ + S_`; `ST + ERE + O`

All of them

> are anagrams of `STORE` with one extra letter. Those extra letters spell `CHANGE`.